# What does the "compiler option" -auxbase-strip do?

Tags: gcc, compilation, compiler-optimization, elf

I just compiled code using the compiler option "-frecord-gcc-switches" to see which options the compiler selects automatically. Now I can see the options in section `.GCC.command.line`. There are several plausible compiler options but also one I cannot find any documentation about. What does `-auxbase-strip png.o` mean. Obviously it does something with png.o, but what does it do exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google search [shows](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2013-08/msg00067.html):

```
Hei Chan:
I am trying to find the document for auxbase and auxbase-strip,
but I can't find any.

Ian Lance Taylor:
They are internal options used to support the -fcompare-debug options.
They are not intended to be used by end users.
```

So, if you *really* want to know what this option does, you'll need to read GCC source (but you shouldn't care).

Comment: In the linked email Ian actually wrote _"They are intended to be used by end users"_ - but in your post it says _"They are *not*..."_. Why is there a difference?

Comment: @aSemy You need to read the entire thread. https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc-help/2013-08/msg00069.html