# f951: Error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-auxbase’

Tags: gcc, fortran, macos-big-sur, apple-m1

I am trying to run fortran code on an Apple Macbook pro M1 chip machine running Big Sur v11.4. When testing my code I get the error

> "f951: Error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-auxbase’".

I've written a test script test.f containing the following

```
program test
    print *, "Hello World"
end program test
```

The output of `gcc -v`:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin20.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

The output of `gfortran -v`:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gfortran
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/Users/pfesi/opt/anaconda3/envs/fermi --build=x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 --host=x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 --target=x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 --with-libiconv-prefix=/Users/pfesi/opt/anaconda3/envs/fermi --enable-languages=fortran --disable-multilib --enable-checking=release --disable-bootstrap --disable-libssp --with-gmp=/Users/pfesi/opt/anaconda3/envs/fermi --with-mpfr=/Users/pfesi/opt/anaconda3/envs/fermi --with-mpc=/Users/pfesi/opt/anaconda3/envs/fermi --with-isl=/Users/pfesi/opt/anaconda3/envs/fermi --with-native-system-header-dir=/Applications/Xcode_12.4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.5.0 (GCC)
```

The output of `which gcc`:

```
/usr/bin/gcc
```

The output of `which gfortran`:

```
/Users/pfesi/opt/anaconda3/envs/fermi/bin/gfortran
```

I'm not an expert on gfortran and any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Writing a file `test.py` containing Fortran code ... . Which command did you give to compile your file?

Comment: Hi Albert, Sorry about the typo, I meant to write test.f and I've corrected it now. So I ran the command $gfortran test.f

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39596418/what-does-the-compiler-option-auxbase-strip-do might be of use

Comment: As might https://gcc-help.gcc.gnu.narkive.com/np3hJuMV/auxbase-vs-auxbase-strip

Comment: Hi Ian, went through your suggestions but for the life of me I cannot understand how any of them solve my issue at hand. I've just started using fortran and find those links confusing.

Comment: These are mainly meant to help others find a solution - they basically say what -auxbase is and why it isn't in the standard documentation. I suspect it's an Apple specific problem, certainly gfortran 7.5 recognises -auxbase on my Linux box, but as I don't use Macs I can't help more.

Comment: Hi Ian, thank you for pointing out it might be an Apple problem. I realised that after i installed x-code I then rushed to google to find out how to install gfortran without testing the x-code version first, which is why i ended up with incompatability issues. So in the end I ended up removing all brew installations and now my code works.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer (caveat emptor…) but I don't like that your `gcc` is the system's one and your `gfortran` is the one installed by anaconda.

Comment: Hi @gboffi, I had tried to install Fortran in my conda virtual environment which caused a lot of issues and resulted in me creating this post. I only later discovered I shouldn't have done any of that in the first place and have since referred back to the Xcode install version which now works fine, both my gcc and gfortran now point to the same location. My only gripe now is that I need to figure out how to install Fortran without Xcode because I had to download 12GB worth of Xcode just to use Fortran :(.

Comment: 12 GB is no more what they used to be…