# Build RocksDB static library using vcpkg and custom gcc on Windows

Tags: gcc, cmake, vcpkg, rocksdb, kotlin-native

I am trying to create Kotlin/Native bindings for RocksDB. This requires that RocksDB is compiled using `gcc` and `g++` version 9.2.0, because that is the only version that Kotlin/Native supports. If I build using 9.5.0 or later, then I get errors:

```
const: error: undefined reference to 'gettid'
```

The `gettid` wrapper was added to glibc 2.30, but Kotlin/Native uses glibc 2.15 when linking.

Since RocksDB has a Makefile that works on Linux and macOS, I am able to successfully build compatible RocksDB libraries. However, I am encountering problems when trying to build RocksDB on Windows.

The [RocksDB wiki explains how to use vcpkg to build RocksDB on Windows](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Building-on-Windows#method-2-win10--visual-studio-20172019), which is quite easy. However, vcpkg will use the system gcc, unless specially instructed otherwise using a special toolchain cmake file.

##### Updating vcpkg to use gcc 9.2.0

vcpkg will accept a custom cmake toolchain file where the location of gcc and g++ can be defined, so I have created that file:

```make
# D:/a/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/konan-toolchain.cmake
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   "C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/gcc.exe")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/g++.exe")
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
```

And then set the file location using the `VCPKG_CHAINLOAD_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` property in the vcpkg triplet file I use to build RocksDB on Windows:

```bash
echo "set(VCPKG_CHAINLOAD_TOOLCHAIN_FILE \"D:/a/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/konan-toolchain.cmake\")" \
>> ./triplets/community/x64-mingw-static.cmake
```

##### vcpkg install fails - "not able to compile a simple test program"

vcpkg seems to be correctly set up to use Kotlin/Native's gcc 9.2.0, but the vcpkg install fails:

```
Detecting compiler hash for triplet x64-windows...
Detecting compiler hash for triplet x64-mingw-static...
error: while detecting compiler information:
The log file content at "D:\a\kotlin-on-the-rocksdb\kotlin-on-the-rocksdb\vcpkg\buildtrees\detect_compiler\stdout-x64-mingw-static.log" is:
-- Found external ninja('1.10.2').
-- Configuring x64-mingw-static
CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_execute_required_process.cmake:112 (message):
    Command failed: C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/ninja.exe -v
    Working Directory: D:/a/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/vcpkg/buildtrees/detect_compiler/x64-mingw-static-rel/vcpkg-parallel-configure
    Error code: 1
    See logs for more information:
      D:\a\kotlin-on-the-rocksdb\kotlin-on-the-rocksdb\vcpkg\buildtrees\detect_compiler\config-x64-mingw-static-rel-CMakeCache.txt.log
      D:\a\kotlin-on-the-rocksdb\kotlin-on-the-rocksdb\vcpkg\buildtrees\detect_compiler\config-x64-mingw-static-out.log

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  scripts/cmake/vcpkg_configure_cmake.cmake:310 (vcpkg_execute_required_process)
  scripts/detect_compiler/portfile.cmake:18 (vcpkg_configure_cmake)
  scripts/ports.cmake:147 (include)

error: vcpkg was unable to detect the active compiler's information. See above for the CMake failure output.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

The log file contains more details:

```
[1/1] "C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" -E chdir ".." "C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" "D:/a/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/vcpkg/scripts/detect_compiler" "-G" "Ninja" "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=D:/a/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/vcpkg/packages/detect_compiler_x64-mingw-static" "-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/ninja.exe" "-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=MinGW" "-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF" "-DVCPKG_CHAINLOAD_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=D:/a/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/konan-toolchain.cmake" "-DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-mingw-static" "-DVCPKG_SET_CHARSET_FLAG=ON" "-DVCPKG_PLATFORM_TOOLSET=external" "-DCMAKE_EXPORT_NO_PACKAGE_REGISTRY=ON" "-DCMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NO_PACKAGE_REGISTRY=ON" "-DCMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NO_SYSTEM_PACKAGE_REGISTRY=ON" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_SYSTEM_RUNTIME_LIBS_SKIP=TRUE" "-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON" "-DVCPKG_APPLOCAL_DEPS=OFF" "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=D:/a/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake" "-DCMAKE_ERROR_ON_ABSOLUTE_INSTALL_DESTINATION=ON" "-DVCPKG_CXX_FLAGS=" "-DVCPKG_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE=" "-DVCPKG_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG=" "-DVCPKG_C_FLAGS=" "-DVCPKG_C_FLAGS_RELEASE=" "-DVCPKG_C_FLAGS_DEBUG=" "-DVCPKG_CRT_LINKAGE=dynamic" "-DVCPKG_LINKER_FLAGS=" "-DVCPKG_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE=" "-DVCPKG_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG=" "-DVCPKG_TARGET_ARCHITECTURE=x64" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR:STRING=lib" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR:STRING=bin" "-D_VCPKG_ROOT_DIR=D:/a/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/vcpkg" "-DZ_VCPKG_ROOT_DIR=D:/a/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/vcpkg" "-D_VCPKG_INSTALLED_DIR=D:/a/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/vcpkg/vcpkg_installed" "-DVCPKG_MANIFEST_INSTALL=OFF"
FAILED: ../CMakeCache.txt 
"C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" -E chdir ".." "C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" "D:/a/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/vcpkg/scripts/detect_compiler" "-G" "Ninja" "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=D:/a/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/vcpkg/packages/detect_compiler_x64-mingw-static" "-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/ninja.exe" "-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=MinGW" "-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF" "-DVCPKG_CHAINLOAD_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=D:/a/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/konan-toolchain.cmake" "-DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-mingw-static" "-DVCPKG_SET_CHARSET_FLAG=ON" "-DVCPKG_PLATFORM_TOOLSET=external" "-DCMAKE_EXPORT_NO_PACKAGE_REGISTRY=ON" "-DCMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NO_PACKAGE_REGISTRY=ON" "-DCMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NO_SYSTEM_PACKAGE_REGISTRY=ON" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_SYSTEM_RUNTIME_LIBS_SKIP=TRUE" "-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON" "-DVCPKG_APPLOCAL_DEPS=OFF" "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=D:/a/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake" "-DCMAKE_ERROR_ON_ABSOLUTE_INSTALL_DESTINATION=ON" "-DVCPKG_CXX_FLAGS=" "-DVCPKG_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE=" "-DVCPKG_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG=" "-DVCPKG_C_FLAGS=" "-DVCPKG_C_FLAGS_RELEASE=" "-DVCPKG_C_FLAGS_DEBUG=" "-DVCPKG_CRT_LINKAGE=dynamic" "-DVCPKG_LINKER_FLAGS=" "-DVCPKG_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE=" "-DVCPKG_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG=" "-DVCPKG_TARGET_ARCHITECTURE=x64" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR:STRING=lib" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR:STRING=bin" "-D_VCPKG_ROOT_DIR=D:/a/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/vcpkg" "-DZ_VCPKG_ROOT_DIR=D:/a/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/vcpkg" "-D_VCPKG_INSTALLED_DIR=D:/a/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/vcpkg/vcpkg_installed" "-DVCPKG_MANIFEST_INSTALL=OFF"
System is unknown to cmake, create:
Platform/MinGW to use this system, please post your config file on discourse.cmake.org so it can be added to cmake
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
System is unknown to cmake, create:
Platform/MinGW to use this system, please post your config file on discourse.cmake.org so it can be added to cmake
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/gcc.exe
System is unknown to cmake, create:
Platform/MinGW to use this system, please post your config file on discourse.cmake.org so it can be added to cmake
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/gcc.exe - works
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
System is unknown to cmake, create:
Platform/MinGW to use this system, please post your config file on discourse.cmake.org so it can be added to cmake
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/g++.exe
System is unknown to cmake, create:
Platform/MinGW to use this system, please post your config file on discourse.cmake.org so it can be added to cmake
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/g++.exe - broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:63 (message):
  The C++ compiler

    "C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/g++.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: D:/a/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/vcpkg/buildtrees/detect_compiler/x64-mingw-static-rel/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-0ck1wg
    
    Run Build Command(s):C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/ninja.exe cmTC_8403e && [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\cmTC_8403e.dir\testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj
    FAILED: CMakeFiles/cmTC_8403e.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj 
    C:\Users\runneradmin\.konan\dependencies\msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2\bin\g++.exe    -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_8403e.dir\testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj -c D:\a\kotlin-on-the-rocksdb\kotlin-on-the-rocksdb\vcpkg\buildtrees\detect_compiler\x64-mingw-static-rel\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-0ck1wg\testCXXCompiler.cxx
    cc1plus.exe: error: unrecognized command-line option '-auxbase-strip'
    cc1plus.exe: error: too many filenames given; type 'cc1plus.exe --help' for usage
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:12 (enable_language)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/a/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/vcpkg/buildtrees/detect_compiler/x64-mingw-static-rel/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "D:/a/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/vcpkg/buildtrees/detect_compiler/x64-mingw-static-rel/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

The log indicates that the correct `gcc`/`g++` commands are used:

```
The C compiler identification is GNU 9.2.0
```

But it fails.

##### What I've tried

###### Increase logging

I have tried increasing the log verbosity, but I wasn't able to get more information.

```make
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
```

###### `unrecognized command-line option '-auxbase-strip'`

I was only able to find that [this option is internal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39596418/what-does-the-compiler-option-auxbase-strip-do), and shouldn't be used. I don't know where it's coming from. [There's no mention of it in vcpkg](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Amicrosoft%2Fvcpkg+auxbase&type=code).

[This question mentions `auxbase`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68601092/f951-error-unrecognized-command-line-option-auxbase), but not `auxbase-strip`, and has no answers.

###### `too many filenames given`

The [answers in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61238227/import-c-error-in-golang-cc1-exe-error-too-many-filenames-given) suggest

- use `-O2` instead of `-o2`, but from what I can tell [RocksDB already uses `-O2`](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/27cf09172c4f212d0aef23b23c802bb791ec9209/Makefile#L88)
- no spaces in paths - but I'm pretty sure that there aren't any...

##### GitHub Workflow

I am using a [GitHub Workflow](https://github.com/aSemy/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/blob/55162c0294b592c143c73b8e0bbedc6762514362/.github/workflows/build_static_libs.yml), so I can automate building with a Windows machine.

Here is a summary:

- Checkout vcpkg

  ```bash
  git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg.git
  cd vcpkg
  ```
- Update the cmake to be a release library (which makes the produced library much smaller) and use the custom toolchain cmake.

  ```bash
  echo "set(VCPKG_BUILD_TYPE release)" >> ./triplets/community/x64-mingw-static.cmake

  echo "set(VCPKG_CHAINLOAD_TOOLCHAIN_FILE \"D:/a/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/konan-toolchain.cmake\")" >> ./triplets/community/x64-mingw-static.cmake
  ```
- set up vcpkg, set the RocksDB version

  ```bash
  ./bootstrap-vcpkg.sh

  touch vcpkg.json;

  cat <<EOT >> vcpkg.json
  {
     "dependencies": [
     "rocksdb",
     "zstd",
     "zlib",
     "snappy",
     "lz4",
     "bzip2"
  ],
  "overrides": [
     { "name": "rocksdb", "version": "${{ env.ROCKSDB_VERSION }}" }
     ]
  }
  EOT

  vcpkg x-update-baseline --add-initial-baseline

  vcpkg install
  ```

#### Additional logs

##### `./vcpkg/buildtrees/detect_compiler/x64-windows-rel/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log`

```
The target system is: Windows - 10.0.20348 - AMD64
The host system is: Windows - 10.0.20348 - AMD64
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" succeeded.
Compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.34.31933/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe 
Build flags: ;/nologo;/DWIN32;/D_WINDOWS;/W3;/utf-8;/MP;
Id flags:  

The output was:
0
CMakeCCompilerId.c


Compilation of the C compiler identification source "CMakeCCompilerId.c" produced "CMakeCCompilerId.exe"

Compilation of the C compiler identification source "CMakeCCompilerId.c" produced "CMakeCCompilerId.obj"

The C compiler identification is MSVC, found in "D:/a/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/vcpkg/buildtrees/detect_compiler/x64-windows-rel/CMakeFiles/3.25.2/CompilerIdC/CMakeCCompilerId.exe"

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
Compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.34.31933/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe 
Build flags: ;/nologo;/DWIN32;/D_WINDOWS;/W3;/utf-8;/GR;/EHsc;/MP;
Id flags:  

The output was:
0
CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp


Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "CMakeCXXCompilerId.exe"

Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "CMakeCXXCompilerId.obj"

The CXX compiler identification is MSVC, found in "D:/a/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/vcpkg/buildtrees/detect_compiler/x64-windows-rel/CMakeFiles/3.25.2/CompilerIdCXX/CMakeCXXCompilerId.exe"
```

##### `./vcpkg/buildtrees/detect_compiler/x64-mingw-static-rel/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log`

```
Detecting C compiler ABI info failed to compile with the following output:
Change Dir: D:/a/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/vcpkg/buildtrees/detect_compiler/x64-mingw-static-rel/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-oiuqqn

Run Build Command(s):C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/ninja.exe cmTC_3a862 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_3a862.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.obj

Using built-in specs.

COLLECT_GCC=C:\Users\runneradmin\.konan\dependencies\msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2\bin\gcc.exe

Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32

Configured with: ../gcc-9.2.0/configure --prefix=/mingw64 --with-local-prefix=/mingw64/local --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-native-system-header-dir=/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include --libexecdir=/mingw64/lib --enable-bootstrap --with-arch=x86-64 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,lto,c++,fortran,ada,objc,obj-c++ --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-libatomic --enable-threads=posix --enable-graphite --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts=yes --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --disable-isl-version-check --enable-lto --enable-libgomp --disable-multilib --enable-checking=release --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --enable-plugin --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/mingw64 --with-mpfr=/mingw64 --with-mpc=/mingw64 --with-isl=/mingw64 --with-pkgversion='Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project' --with-bugurl=https://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2 --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld

Thread model: posix

gcc version 9.2.0 (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 

COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_3a862.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.obj' '-c' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'

 C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/cc1.exe -quiet -v -iprefix C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/ -D_REENTRANT C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/CMakeCCompilerABI.c -quiet -dumpbase CMakeCCompilerABI.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase-strip CMakeFiles/cmTC_3a862.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.obj -version -o C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTdIyhC.s

GNU C17 (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) version 9.2.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)

    compiled by GNU C version 9.2.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 4.0.2, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.21-GMP



warning: GMP header version 6.1.2 differs from library version 6.2.1.

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072

ignoring duplicate directory "C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/include"

ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/building/msys64/mingw64/include"

ignoring nonexistent directory "/mingw64/include"

ignoring duplicate directory "C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/include-fixed"

ignoring duplicate directory "C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include"

ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/building/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include"

#include "..." search starts here:

#include <...> search starts here:

 C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/include

 C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../include

 C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/include-fixed

 C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include

End of search list.

GNU C17 (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) version 9.2.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)

    compiled by GNU C version 9.2.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 4.0.2, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.21-GMP



warning: GMP header version 6.1.2 differs from library version 6.2.1.

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072

Compiler executable checksum: 3bcdf03344e3ad7cb057c2ec82f696e6

COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_3a862.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.obj' '-c' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'

 C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/as.exe -v -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_3a862.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.obj C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTdIyhC.s

GNU assembler version 2.32 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.32

COMPILER_PATH=C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/;C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/../lib/gcc/;C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/

LIBRARY_PATH=C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/;C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/../lib/gcc/;C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/;C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../lib/;C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/;C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../

COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_3a862.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.obj' '-c' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'

[2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_3a862

Using built-in specs.

COLLECT_GCC=C:\Users\runneradmin\.konan\dependencies\msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2\bin\gcc.exe

Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32

Configured with: ../gcc-9.2.0/configure --prefix=/mingw64 --with-local-prefix=/mingw64/local --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-native-system-header-dir=/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include --libexecdir=/mingw64/lib --enable-bootstrap --with-arch=x86-64 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,lto,c++,fortran,ada,objc,obj-c++ --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-libatomic --enable-threads=posix --enable-graphite --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts=yes --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --disable-isl-version-check --enable-lto --enable-libgomp --disable-multilib --enable-checking=release --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --enable-plugin --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/mingw64 --with-mpfr=/mingw64 --with-mpc=/mingw64 --with-isl=/mingw64 --with-pkgversion='Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project' --with-bugurl=https://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2 --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld

Thread model: posix

gcc version 9.2.0 (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 

COMPILER_PATH=C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/;C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/../lib/gcc/;C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/

LIBRARY_PATH=C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/;C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/../lib/gcc/;C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/;C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../lib/;C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/;C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../

COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'cmTC_3a862.exe' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'

 C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/collect2.exe -plugin C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/liblto_plugin-0.dll -plugin-opt= -plugin-opt=-fresolution=C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc5FiNtF.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_eh -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lpthread -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-ladvapi32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lshell32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-luser32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_eh -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -m i386pep -Bdynamic -o cmTC_3a862.exe C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/crtbegin.o -LC:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0 -LC:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/../lib/gcc -LC:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib -LC:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../lib -LC:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -LC:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../.. CMakeFiles/cmTC_3a862.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.obj -lmingw32 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -lpthread -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmingw32 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/default-manifest.o C:/Users/runneradmin/.konan/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/crtend.o

COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'cmTC_3a862.exe' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'



Cannot copy output executable
  ''
to destination specified by COPY_FILE:
  'D:/a/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/vcpkg/buildtrees/detect_compiler/x64-mingw-static-rel/CMakeFiles/3.25.2/CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_C.bin'
Recorded try_compile output location doesn't exist:
  D:/a/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/vcpkg/buildtrees/detect_compiler/x64-mingw-static-rel/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-oiuqqn/cmTC_3a862


Checking whether the CXX compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
Checking whether the CXX compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info failed to compile with the following output:
Change Dir: D:/a/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/vcpkg/buildtrees/detect_compiler/x64-mingw-static-rel/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-s77rm4

Run Build Command(s):C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/ninja.exe cmTC_4db65 && [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\cmTC_4db65.dir\CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.obj

FAILED: CMakeFiles/cmTC_4db65.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.obj 

C:\Users\runneradmin\.konan\dependencies\msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2\bin\g++.exe    -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_4db65.dir\CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.obj -c "C:\Program Files\CMake\share\cmake-3.25\Modules\CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp"

cc1plus.exe: error: unrecognized command-line option '-auxbase-strip'
cc1plus.exe: error: too many filenames given; type 'cc1plus.exe --help' for usage
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.





Determining if the C++ compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: D:/a/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/vcpkg/buildtrees/detect_compiler/x64-mingw-static-rel/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-552faq

Run Build Command(s):C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/ninja.exe cmTC_e2caf && [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\cmTC_e2caf.dir\testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj

FAILED: CMakeFiles/cmTC_e2caf.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj 

C:\Users\runneradmin\.konan\dependencies\msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-2\bin\g++.exe    -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_e2caf.dir\testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj -c D:\a\kotlin-on-the-rocksdb\kotlin-on-the-rocksdb\vcpkg\buildtrees\detect_compiler\x64-mingw-static-rel\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-552faq\testCXXCompiler.cxx

cc1plus.exe: error: unrecognized command-line option '-auxbase-strip'
cc1plus.exe: error: too many filenames given; type 'cc1plus.exe --help' for usage
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: Have you checked See also "D:/a/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/kotlin-on-the-rocksdb/vcpkg/buildtrees/detect_compiler/x64-mingw-static-rel/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log". for the error?

Comment: @AlexanderNeumann I've added CMakeError.log. There's some additional errors in there, `g++.exe: fatal error: no input files`, but I'm not sure what they mean.